# Fazer o conteúdo da Div aparecer apenas quando clico em um botão

Tags: javascript, html, collapse

Olá!

Estou com dificuldade em fazer com que ao acessar a página os meus conteúdos de collapse fiquem ocultos.

Tenho 3 botões com conteúdo, e assim que acesso a página no server, os 3 conteúdos aparecem de uma vez.

Eu gostaria que não aparecesse nem um ao iniciar a página e conforme for clicando nos botões ir aparecendo os conteúdos.

**Javascript:**

```
function Conteudo(el){
var display = document.getElementById(el).style.display;
    if(display == "none")
        document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'block';
    else
        document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'none';}
```

**Html:**

```
      <div class="linhas-esquadros" id="linhas-esquadros">

          <form style="display: inline" method="get">
            <button id="linha-essencial" type="button" onclick="Conteudo('container-linha-essencial')" class="on-button-essencial off-button-essencial"><h2>Linha <b>Essencial®</b></h2></button>
              </form>

              <form style="display: inline" method="get">
                <button id="linha-pro" type="button" onclick="Conteudo('container-linha-pro')" class="on-button-pro off-button-pro"><h2>Linha <b>Pro®</b></h2></button>
                  </form>

                  <form style="display: inline" method="get">
                    <button id="linha-premium" type="button" onclick="Conteudo('container-linha-premium')" class="on-button-premium off-button-premium"><h2>Linha <b>Premium®</b></h2></button>
                      </form>
          </div>
        </section>

<div id="container-linha-essencial">...</div>
<div id="container-linha-pro">...</div>
<div id="container-linha-premium">...</div>

</div>
```

Comment: <div id="container-linha-essencial"> altere para `<div id="container-linha-essencial" style="dysplay: none">`

Comment: Resolvido Alvaro, obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assim acredito que você conseguirá o que precisa

```js
function Conteudo(el){
var display = document.getElementById(el).style.display;
    if(display == "none")
        document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'block';
    else
        document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'none';}
```

```html
<section>
      <div class="linhas-esquadros" id="linhas-esquadros">

          <form style="display: inline" method="get">
            <button id="linha-essencial" type="button" onclick="Conteudo('container-linha-essencial')" class="on-button-essencial off-button-essencial"><h2>Linha <b>Essencial®</b></h2></button>
              </form>

              <form style="display: inline" method="get">
                <button id="linha-pro" type="button" onclick="Conteudo('container-linha-pro')" class="on-button-pro off-button-pro"><h2>Linha <b>Pro®</b></h2></button>
                  </form>

                  <form style="display: inline" method="get">
                    <button id="linha-premium" type="button" onclick="Conteudo('container-linha-premium')" class="on-button-premium off-button-premium"><h2>Linha <b>Premium®</b></h2></button>
                      </form>
          </div>
          
        </section>

<div id="container-linha-essencial" style="display: none">...</div>
<div id="container-linha-pro" style="display: none">...</div>
<div id="container-linha-premium" style="display: none">...</div>
```

Comment: Isso mesmo, muito obrigado. Era mais simples que imaginava.